# Mod not doing his job

Tags: discussion

A recent [answer of mine in the C++ tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34734619/464581) accumulated a host of hostile comments from some user, accusing me of going after “low hanging fruit”, of duplicating some unspecified existing answer (i.e. plagiarism), etc.

I flagged the first comment and posted a comment that I flagged it, and considering the personal attack I included the info that I thought of the user as a sh******g, just for good measure. I expected some mod to delete both comments, and maybe reprimand me for being so frank instead of devious. I.e. I expected the flagging plus comment-to-be-flagged to work to both remove the noise and maybe reduce the guy's enthusiasm for generating such noise. Indeed that comment was upvoted by someone.

Then followed a barrage of further attacks, with the mod deleting my comments that I'd flagged them.

I have no quarrel with a mod deleting my comments, indeed the first was designed to be deleted, and all were expected to be deleted: I expected all that commentary to be deleted. I do have a quarrel with that mod **not working to reduce the noise level**, and leaving misleading, personal attacks. It's not what a mod should do.

[image]

Answer (score 28):

Actually, a mod was never involved (until just now; more on that momentarily). The comments in question were all either (1) deleted by the person who wrote them or (2) flagged by the "Community" user as offensive and effectively deleted automatically because they were obviously abusive or obscene.

Now that you have posted about it on Meta, though, a mod *has* gotten involved - namely, me - and removed all of the comments, not one of which was both constructive and non-obsolete.

The moral here is pretty clear: If you don't want your comments to be deleted, don't post useless or offensive comments.

Comment: Thanks for deleting the comments, even if your comment here, "If you don't want your comments to be deleted, don't post useless or offensive comments.", indicates that you **think** you did me a disservice. And even if there was no way all the comments could have been automatically flagged (the first one could have been, maybe the second). Jees.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Not sure what you're talking about. If anything, deleting those comments probably helps you by keeping your post from attracting Meta-effect downvotes. Keep it clean, please.

Comment: It's OK. I wanted the comments deleted, you deleted them, that's fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

> if you're going to go after the low hanging fruit, at least vote to close as well when the duplicate has already been posted.

This comment, in and of itself, is not offensive. It's not a personal attack; nay, it's an attempt to (rather politely) ask you to help out closing duplicates. There is some debate about whether we should be answering these; that's irrelevant here and I won't go into it.

I can't speak for any other comments the user may have made. If they legitimately said something offensive to you in a later, now deleted comment, is something only a moderator could say.

---

Now, the crux of your question:

> I expected all that commentary to be deleted.

It's vital that you make it known *in the flag itself* that you think all the comments there can be deleted. The comment flag UI is... somewhat painful, and isn't conducive to seeing context easily:

> [image]

We have to click through to the post if we want to see all the comments. On smaller sites, I have the luxury of doing this for every flag. On large sites like SO, I imagine that moderators tend to delete clear-cut comments directly from the dashboard - remember, we're talking about hundreds or thousands of flags on a daily basis.

That can, and should, be improved, but at this point we just need to work with the moderators on it. Making life easy for them is good for everyone, and avoids miscommunications like this.

If you believe a moderator should do something specific, make it clear in the flag text. Either use a custom flag on the post itself or write custom text in a comment flag.

Comment: Well, I don't consider "go after low hanging fruit" to be polite at all, not to say "rather politely". Just the opposite: I consider that very personal and derogatory. And at the time there was no clear duplicate identified (someone had mentioned a question with tens of answers about different possible ways to get a linker error). A duplicate was later identified and then I closed the question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm not going to comment on that specifically; you think it's offensive and I (along with at least some of the community) don't. I mostly want to address the "not doing your job" part of your question. It's possible that the user was *wrong*, doesn't mean it's offensive.

Comment: Well, I can see that if a mod doesn't see the context, it can work out that way. So the advice about using a custom flag with text appears to be good. But this then seems to be a definite potential for improvement in the SO infrastructure.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Definitely. For the most part, moderator tools are *awesome* here. The issue is in coming up with a UI worth implementing (not just a minor enhancement, if we're going to do something to this let's do it right the first time). If you have suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: All that said, I don't find it completely believable that whoever the mod was, didn't see all the flagged comments. Which constituted all of the context. Also, I don't buy the idea that "going after low hanging fruit" and "duplicating existing answers" is not offensive, or at the least not constructive, noise. So, my very strong perception that some moderator didn't do his job, stands, sorry. But thanks for the flagging advice, I'll do that if or when it becomes relevant again. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf At the end of the day, for someone having such a rather low threshold of interpreting comments as downright offensive, you tend to be rather liberal in throwing out words that a majority of people would call clearly offensive, be that for "good measure" or not.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I do master the art of the underhanded snide remark, which you appear to prefer, but I prefer to think straight and talk straight. The roundabout indirect putdowns are not always understood by the intended recipient, and they sure don't attract moderators, which was part of my purpose. I don't share your opinion of low threshold, at all, nor your opinion that I throw out words. I think people should best be deliberate about what they do, and know what they want to achieve. Do you.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If you wanted to be deliberate and direct then the obvious choice would have been to flag the comments for moderator attention, rather than trying to indirectly attract them with messages you were well aware were inappropriate. Anyway, nevermind, the answers here have clarified the matter sufficiently already.

Comment: @ChristianRau: You're making noise. The remarks *were* flagged.

Answer (score 22):

I know this can be hard, but when it looks like one of these situations is about to break out, the *very ground beneath you* becomes an [event horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon).

Unless you're amiable to the idea of mutual [spaghettification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification), where you combine in very strange, yet intimate ways with the combatant, you have to pull the emergency escape lever which is this:

> This line of discourse has derailed; I'm alerting a moderator to clean up the mess we've made and not participating in it any longer.

But then you *really do* have to walk away, or get sucked in, ***pulled apart***, and combined with them into angry pasta.

If you feel like you need to do more, replace the `;` with a `,` — then let out a sinister laugh and be delighted with the knowledge that you hit them with a [comma splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice).

Comment: Thanks. You made me smile. :)